# different chi2 value in sklearn and scipy.stats for the same contingency table

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, feature-selection

```
X=np.array([7.20E+01,2.40E+01,0.00E+00,9.00E+00,0.00E+00,3.00E+00,0.00E+00,5.40E01,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,3.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,1.50E+01,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,1.11E+02,2.70E+01,0.00E+00,6.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
3.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
1.70E+01,
3.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
8.00E+00,
5.20E+01,
1.80E+01,
5.20E+01,
5.20E+01,
5.00E+01,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00,
0.00E+00])


y=np.array([0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00
1.00E+00])
```

This is the X(I have just taken one feature for now for simplicity) and y for 146 samples.The first 73 are of class(0) and the other 73 are of class(1).

Now I want to calculate the chi2 scores for this feature.I have used the sklearn.feature_selection.chi2 which is giving me the answer `579` and the same if I do in scipy.stats.chi2_contingency its giving 21 as the answer.

Codes used-

```
obs = np.array([[0, 19], [73,54]])
scipy.stats.chi2_contingency(obs,correction=False)
```

this gives 21 as the answer which I think should be the correct answer also as the formula is `(a*d-b*c)**2*float(n)/((a+c)*(b+d)*(a+b)*(c+d))`

but the sklearn is giving 579 with this code-

```
X_d= X.reshape(-1,1)
y_d=y.reshape(-1,1)
print(sklearn.feature_selection.chi2(X_d, y_d))
```

Why are the chi2 values different in both the cases?

edit  -How I am creating the contingency table in the scipy case

[image]

[image]

formula for reference-

so number of non zero values I am getting in 0(negative class) is 19.Total number of samples is 146 and number of non zero values in positve class is 0.Based on this information the values I get for A B C D N are `0 19 73 54 146` which I feed to the scipy.stats function.

Comment: Please give a *consistent* example; why you use different data inputs in the two cases (`obs` and `X, Y`)???

Comment: @desertnaut I didnt get you....do you mean in scipy.stats.chi2_contingency and sklearn.feature_selection.chi2(X_d, y_d) ?

Comment: Yes, in the first case your input is `obs`, while in the second is `X_d, Y_d`, with these variables being different

Comment: @desertnaut...this is because in sklearn the function takes as input the entire feature vector table and in the case of scipy.stats it takes as input the contingency table of two variables which in this case is the feature and class(in case of feature selection algos in general)

Comment: I will edit and add also how I am creating the contingency table for the said data

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The code that you have shown is helpful, but it is not in a state that we can run to reproduce your results.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser is it a problem with the dataset I provided or the code for it?